# DBPEDIA + SPARQL Selecting films in function of their genre

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Is it possible to get the list of films in function of their genre?

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?film_title ?film_abstract ?film_genre
WHERE {
?film_title rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
?film_title rdfs:comment ?film_abstract .
?film_genre <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/genre> ?film_genre .
FILTER(lang(?film_abstract) = "en" ).

}
LIMIT 20
```

But probably I've doing something wrong !

Thanks,
Danilo

Comment: If you don't say why it's not working it's difficult to help

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a simple typo on your part.  The third triple pattern should be the following:

```
 ?film_title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/genre> ?film_genre
```

Also the FILTER you are using may make the query very slow, try using the following instead:

```
 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?film_abstract), "en"))
```

Though having played with your query there doesn't appear to be any data that actually matches your query in DBPedia.  Essentially the genre property you are using appears only to be applied to music and not to films so you should remove the third triple pattern entirely if you actually want to get any results

Comment: You're righ, there was a typo in my third pattern.

Comment: Hy RobV and thanks for the suggestions.
I thought it was possible to determine the list of movies from their genre.
In fact, looking at the class diagram of ontologies (http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes)
I saw that a property of class 'film' (http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/Film) was their 'genre'

So I wanted to pull out all the movies that have, for example the genre "Action_Movie"

Do you know another way to do this?

Thanks